# What are the available dot net core dependencies?

Tags: nuget, .net-core, nuget-package-restore

I recently started experimenting with dot net core , and one of my major problems was restoring the dependencies. I went into the the project.json file and added some dependencies , the name was correct but the version was just trial and error until i reached the recent version. I couldn't seem to find any documentation online either , can anyone help me find or show me where i can find a proper list of all the dot net core dependencies and their latest version ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com

Comment: Been there already

Comment: Go back again and spend more time there. The [help/on-topic] says ***Questions asking us to recommend or find** a book, tool, software library, tutorial or **other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: There is no reliable way. You can use http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net to search and then use normal NuGet way to find the latest version.

Comment: If you are in Visual Studio 2015 (and maybe also in VS Code?) its IntelliSense helps. Open *package.json*, type the package ID within quotes, then the colon, then within the quotes for version number hit CTRL + Space and wait until a version list is loaded

Answer (score 0):

I have used core to great success. The package manager in VS2015 and 2017 does a great job of resolving both the version you are using and other available versions. If you are working directly with project.json ( not available in VS2017, dependencies have been moved back to the project file ), it will only tell you what packages are available via your user cache. ( found in C:\Users\YourUserNameHere.nuget\packages for both vs2015 and 2017 ) by typing the package name and then letting intellisense do it's thing.

Of course once you do a get of a package it is then available from your cache.